# Where is the module in James and Liebeck's FG module

Tags: representation-theory

On p. 39 of James and Liebeck's book "Representations and Characters of Groups"  The term FG module is defined for F a field, G a group V a vectors space and an action of G on V is defined.

Where is the module in all this?  My understanding is that a module is a vector space with multiplication by a ring (instead of a field).  A group is not a Ring although it operates on V.

Where is a classically defined module in all this?  Perhaps FG module is just a term of art

Comment: $FG$ likely refers to the group ring of $G$ over $F$. You can read more about group rings here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring

Answer (score 2):

If $R$ is a ring, and $G$ is a group, then the **group ring** $\pmb{RG}$ is the ring of formal sums
$$
RG \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \bigg\{\widetilde\sum_{g\in G}r_gg : r_g\in R,\ g\in G\bigg\},
$$
where $\widetilde\sum$ means that all but finitely many summands are $0$. Addition is defined componentwise, and multiplication is handled like it is for polynomials.

Specializing to the case where $R = F$ is a field, $FG$ is still a ring, and if $V$ is an $F$-vector space on which $G$ acts, then $V$ is naturally an $FG$-module, where we define the module action for $\widetilde \sum_{g\in G}r_gg\in FG$ and $v\in V$ by
$$
\bigg(\widetilde \sum_{g\in G}r_gg\bigg)\cdot v\ \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \ \widetilde\sum_{g\in G}r_g(g\cdot v).
$$
Note the $\cdot$ on the right-hand side of this equation is the action of $G$ on $V$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Alex Ortiz is really great and was very helpful for me, but I think it’s possible to more directly address the original question: why does a $FG$-module (for example, as defined by James & Liebeck) qualify as a module?

The key to a module is to have the scalars (used in scalar multiplication of the vectors) as members of a ring instead of a field. A “$FG$-module” is a straightforward case of that. Since there is a field $F$ involved, a possible point of confusion is whether the scalars are members of the field $F$ now, instead of coming from a ring. But it is $FG$, a **group ring**, that is the set in which the scalars are members.

So to summarize: a $FG$-module is a module where the scalars are members of a group ring $FG$. The group ring $FG$ is defined and its module action is defined in the answer from Alex Ortiz above.

Comment: Liebeck defines an $FG$-module, as having 5 properties on p. 39. $ vg \in V$, $v(gH) = (vg)h$, $v1=v$, $(\lambda v) g = \lambda (vg)$, and lastly $(u+v)g = ug + vg$. Conspicuously absent is the following that we would expect for a module, $v(g+h) = vg + hv$. Later in chapter 6 they introduce the Group Algebra which gives you a ring to form a module, but they never update there definition and instead just say that the group algebra, FG, acts on an FG-module.